# Enum values().length vs private field

Tags: java, enums

I have enumeration like this:

```
public enum Configuration {
    XML(1),
    XSLT(10),
    TXT(100),
    HTML(2),
    DB(20);

    private final int id;
    private Configuration(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId() { return id; }
}
```

Sometimes I need to check how many fields I have in enumeration. What is the best solution?
Should I use a method "values().length"? Or maybe, I must create constant field in enumeration like this:

```
public enum Configuration {
    XML(1),
    XSLT(10),
    TXT(100),
    HTML(2),
    DB(20);

    private final int id;
    private Configuration(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId() { return id; }

    public static final int Size = 5;
}
```

What is the fastest and more elegant solution?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Using `values().length` will create a new copy of the array every time you call it. I sometimes create my own `List` (or set, or map, whatever I need) to avoid this pointless copying. I *wouldn't* hard-code it though... if you only need the size, I'd just use:

```
private static final int size = Configuration.values().length;
```

at the end. By the time that is evaluated, all the values will have been initialized. This avoids the DRY and inconsistency concerns raised in other answers.

Of course, this is a bit of a micro-optimisation in itself... but one which ends up with *simpler* code in the end, IMO. Calling `values().length` from elsewhere doesn't express what you're interested in, which is *just* the size of the enum - the fact that you get at it through an array of values is incidental and distracting, IMO.

An alternative to using `values()` is to use `EnumSet.allOf().size()` which for small enums will be pretty cheap - but again, it's not as readable as just having a `size` field.

Comment: If you want to adhere to the Java naming conventions, shouldn't you name that constant `SIZE` rather than `size`?

Comment: @Jubobs: I certainly would for a public constant, but for a private one I don't mind much either way. Note that it's not a *compile-time* constant.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your rationale.

Comment: Keeping size as private then just needs the getter added: public int getSize(){return size;} . The size is now available for public use without using a nasty constant.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using `values().length`.  This is far more elegant and the performance overhead versus using a constant will be negligable.  Also, you eliminate the risk of the constant ever becoming out of step with the actual length of the enumeration.

Answer (score 8):

By storing the count you're violating the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so unless you have a very good reason, you shouldn't.

Comment: Aaarrgghh - I was desperately googling for this but forgot what it was called!

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to use a constant initialized on top of the values() method.

```
public enum Colors {
    BLUE, GREEN, FUCHSIA;
    public static int length = Colors.values().length;
}
```

This way you have an automatically updated constant and still avoid that "values()" overhead.