# What is a better way to find the size of the enum?

Tags: java, oop, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Enum values().length vs private field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741708/enum-values-length-vs-private-field)

I want to know how which of these ways to find the size of the *enum* is better.

This way:

```
public enum Company {

    AUDI(4), BMW(5), CADILLAC(11), FORD(44), JAGUAR(45);

    private final int id;
    public final int length = Company.values().length;

    private Company(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Or this way:

```
public enum Company {

    AUDI(4), BMW(5), CADILLAC(11), FORD(44), JAGUAR(45);

    private final int id;
    public final int length = 5;

    private Company(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: @downvote... whonsoever has downvoted this question please add a reason below. That will help me to understand whats wrong.

Comment: thnx EJP for upvoting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one, but make it `static` so you don't make multiple copies of the array.

```
public final static int length = Company.values().length;
```

Comment: since we have declare it as static whenever we use length it wont create new array right??? please do reply.

Comment: @amod0017 yes, static variables are only initialised once.

Comment: its great can u suggest me how can i get the enum items as a string array. values method is giving me error.

Comment: `values()` will give you a `Company[]` array. Loop over the array and call `toString` to convert each enum to a String and store into a different array.

Comment: ok... i want to avoid looping and all is there is any better way possible??

Comment: i used your way only and its working f9. thnx for the help.

Answer (score 5):

given -

```
enum Widgets {TINY, SMALL, AVERAGE, BIG};
```

the size of Widgets is:

```
Widgets.values().length
```

Comment: Sorry I'm probably just missing something, but isn't that what his first example is?

Comment: i dont want to use this becuase it will create array all the time. length should be inside enum.

Answer (score 2):

Neither way. Just use myEnum.values().size where you need it.

Comment: it will create array again and again. Please have a look at similar question asked in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the first way is better. This way, you don't have to manually update the length variable if you add more companies to the enum.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the second way is that every time you add a new value, you have to update the length manually.

For the first method, it's dynamic and you can even put it static (since it will take an integer per enum instance if you don't):

```
public final static int length= Company.values().length;
```

But I would suggest using 'Company.values().length' since it's more standard.