# C-like enum in Java

Tags: java, c++, arrays, enums

I'm trying to find a Java equivalent for the following convenience in C++:

```
enum {
  ANIMAL_CAT = 0,
  ANIMAL_RAT,
  ANIMAL_BAT, ...
  NUM_ANIMALS
};

Animal animals[NUM_ANIMALS];

animals[ANIMAL_CAT].mNumLegs = 4;
animals[ANIMAL_RAT].mNumLegs = 4; ...
```

I know this isn't the prettiest thing in the world, but I can add a new ANIMAL_xxx anywhere in the enum and all the following entries will be automatically adjusted. Is there a clean way to do this in Java?

---

Thanks for the responses, but I may have alluded to a greater simplicity than I intended.

I'm working on a game, where there's a physics, AI engine, etc. I'm trying to consolidate all the information I need for each type of entity (some have only a physical manifestation, while some have both phys and AI, etc...), so that I can easily add/modify types (so, animal is a bad example, because I may need rocks, plants, etc...).

I'm using a class to store the type info, while other classes rely on that class to look up the attributes (dimensions, bitmap index, hasAi, etc...) In the end, I'm trying to clean up something similar to the following, while allowing me to easily add new types:

```
class UnitTypeInfo {
  UnitTypeInfo() {
    mTypes = new TypeInfo[NUM_TYPES];

    // and allocate...

    // initialize TypeInfos here
    mTypes[TYPE_CAT].mType = TYPE_CAT;
    mTypes[TYPE_CAT].mMass = 10.0f;
    mTypes[TYPE_CAT] ...

    mTypes[TYPE_ROCK].mType = TYPE_ROCK;
    ...
  }

  public class TypeInfo {
    public int mType;
    public int mRawResourceHandle;
    public float mMass;
    public Vector2d mDimensions;
    public float mHealth;
    public boolean mHasAi;
    ...
  }

  public static final int TYPE_CAT = 0;
  public static final int TYPE_ROCK = 1;
  public static final int TYPE_TREE = 2; ...
  public static final int NUM_TYPES = ???; // the last TYPE_ + 1

  public TypeInfo mTypes[];
}
```

Now, this seems like some sort of XML implementation might be the 'right' thing to do, but I'm not sure about how to do that (new to Java). Anyhow, the other classes can easily just use unitTypeInfo.mTypes[UnitTypeInfo.TYPE_CAT].mMass (instantiated) to look up the cat's mass. However, if I want to add a TYPE_DOG underneath the TYPE_CAT definition, I have to update everything underneath it (lazy, I know, but let's figure there are a few more types.)

Enums offer an easy solution to this problem in C++, but in Java, the simplest solution I can can up with now requires something like: unitTypeInfo.mTypes[UnitTypeInfo.mTypeEnum.TYPE_CAT.ordinal()].mMass - and while I suppose this isn't *much* worse than my already crummy solution, it does add a fair bit more indirection and an actual method call (to a method that most sources do not seem to encourage).

One more thing is that I want to be able to call a switch(type), so that might also limit the possible solutions.

Anyhow, I'm starting to get the idea that there must be a much better solution to this whole problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Related question here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741708/enum-values-length-vs-private-field

Comment: No reason to have an array of all enums in the first place - java's enums are one of its best features which I always sadly miss in C++/C# where its just syntactic sugar around an "int". Although in this particular case I wouldn't use an enum to begin with but a class - seems like the better architecture (though that may depend on the exact usage and so on..)

Answer (score 7):

"Classic" java always used "static final int ANIMAL_CAT = 0;" in cases like this.

JDK 1.5 introduced "type-safe enums":

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=1

You can now do this (a very common practice):

```
enum Quark {
    /*
    * These are called "enum constants".
    * An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its
    * enum constants. They are implicitly "public static final".
    * Each enum constant corresponds to a call to a constructor.
    * When no args follow an enum constant, then the no-argument constructor
    * is used to create the corresponding object.
    */
    UP,
    DOWN,
    CHARM,
    STRANGE,
    BOTTOM,
    TOP
  }
```

Or you can do this:

```
/**
  * Example 2 - adding a constructor to an enum.
  *
  * If no constructor is added, then the usual default constructor
  * is created by the system, and declarations of the
  * enum constants will correspond to calling this default constructor.
  */
  public enum Lepton {
    //each constant implicity calls a constructor :
    ELECTRON(-1, 1.0E-31),
    NEUTRINO(0, 0.0);

    /* 
    * This constructor is private.
    * Legal to declare a non-private constructor, but not legal
    * to use such a constructor outside the enum.
    * Can never use "new" with any enum, even inside the enum 
    * class itself.
    */
    private Lepton(int aCharge, double aMass){
      //cannot call super ctor here
      //calls to "this" ctors allowed
      fCharge = aCharge;
      fMass = aMass;
    }
    final int getCharge() {
      return fCharge;
    }
    final double getMass() {
      return fMass;
    }
    private final int fCharge;
    private final double fMass;
  }
```

Here's the official documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Comment: +1 for the choice of example. But you should watch out, since `Lepton.NEUTRINO` may travel faster than light.

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply this:

```
public enum Animal {
    CAT(4), RAT(4), BAT(4), CHICKEN(2), ..., ANT(6), SPIDER(8);

    // A simple attribute, like any other java class.
    // Final to ensure it will never change.
    private final int legs;

    // Note that this constructor is private.
    private Animal(int legs) {
        this.legs = legs;
    }

    // A method, like any other class.
    public int getLegs() {
        return legs;
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
// How to get all the animals in the enum.
Animal[] animals = Animal.values();

// How to get the number of animals.
int numAnimals = animals.length;

// How to get the number of legs of some animal.
int howManyLegsHaveTheAnt = Animal.ANT.getLegs();
int howManyLegsHaveTheFirstAnimal = animals[0].getLegs();

// How to get the name of a given animal.
String theFirstAnimalName = animals[0].name(); // Will return "CAT".

// How to get the position in the enum of some animal.
int antPositionInTheEnum = Animal.ANT.ordinal();

// How to get an animal given its name.
Animal rat = Enum.valueOf(Animal.class, "RAT");
Animal someAnimal = Enum.valueOf(Animal.class, animalName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I may have alluded to a greater simplicity than I intended.

Comment: Java is a verbose language. Simplicity in java does not means small code. Believe it, this code is simple. Further, I have readed your edit to the question, which turned it in a very different question, so I will post another answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No Java don't have C-like enums. Although the same can be achieved in java with series of statements like below:

```
public static final int GREEN = 1;
public static final int RED   = 2;
public static final int BLUE  = 3;
```

Java enums are different.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, using enums is not a good idea. Enums are inherently immutable things, a fixed set where no new elements may be invented and no existing elements may be destroyed. Weekdays, months of the year and cards suits are a good example of enums, the existed set is fixed and immutable, no new element will never be created and no existing element will ever be destroyed. Animal types, music genres, tilesets, etc, does not follows these rules.

The better is the most obvious: Define an interface or abstract class Animal. And defines all the types of animals as a subtyping.

Switches are as evil as goto, they are simple, are easy to use, looks innocent, but in the end transforms your code in a spaghetti jungle. Instead of using the switches that you want, use polymorphism. I.E:

```
// Don't:
public class SomeClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        switch (animal.id) {
            case TYPE_CAT:
                doSomethingThatCatDoes();
                doSomethingElse();
                anotherThing();
                break;

            case TYPE_DOG:
                bark();
                doSomethingThatDogDoes();
                otherThing();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Do:
public interface Animal {
    public void myMethodAction();
    // Other methods.
}

public class Cat implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void myMethodAction() {
        doSomethingThatCatDoes();
        doSomethingElse();
        anotherThing();
    }
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void myMethodAction() {
        bark();
        doSomethingThatDogDoes();
        otherThing();
    }
}

public class SomeClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        animal.myMethodAction();
    }
}
```

The code tends to become larger when you do this, but this does not means more complex. Instead, it became better organized, because the SomeClass does not needs to know the exact animal type anymore, The logic particular for each animal type is all in one only place, and if you need to change the behaviour of an animal, you won't need to search and change a lot of very distant places. Further, it becomes much easier to add new animal types. As you should see, your project becames more flexible for future changes (i.e, easier to change, harder to break).

You should note that I did not used explicit ids. Avoid ids, because they are vicious and you already have them implicity. Each object has a unique memory address, and that memory address is the id. So, your `public int mType;` field would become a `public Class<? extends Animal> mType;`. If you really need these ids, make them as short-lived as possible and the less used as possible. The reason for this is to use OO beter (I will explain this below).

More, your TypeInfo is just a bunch of public attributes. Please, never-never-never think about of doing this. In OO, public attributes are as hateful as gotos and switches, and THEY SURELY WILL WITH 100% OF PROBABILITY undermine your project. Instead, whatever you do that needs to handle the fields, put in the TypeInfo class and make the fields private. This does not means replacing public attributes by brain-dead getters and setters, instead, put your business logic there.

I strongly recommend that you study some OO deeper. Specifically true encapsulation (some people says that adding a bunch of brain-dead getters and setters is ok, but it isn´t, this is not true encapsulation). Study polymorphism, not just what it is and how it works, but how you can use it and why. And the most important, study cohesion and coupling, to make classes that makes sense, fairly independent, reusable and flexible.