# How to get number of possible items of an Enum?

Tags: java, kotlin, enums

Is there a builtin way to get the number of items of an Enum with something like `Myenum.length`,

Or do I have to implement myself a function `int size()` hardcording the number of element?

Comment: Are you talking about enums or an Enumeration ? These are not the same.

Comment: Was talking about enums. Problem is that in french enums is a shorthand for "enumeration".(as in english I tend to think). so wasn't speaking of the interface.

Comment: Is it OK that I added the Kotlin tag? I Googled a Kotlin solution and ended up here.

Comment: Refer to [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1741708/8583692).

Comment: Also see [this youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48872) that proposes a performant replacement for `Enum.values()` in Kotiln.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes you can use the `Enum.values()` method to get an array of Enum values then use the `length` property.

```
public class Main {
    enum WORKDAYS { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(WORKDAYS.values().length);
        // prints 5
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/zMB6pG

Comment: `Enum.values()` allocates a new array every time so it's not recommended for high call rate (i.e. for-loop condition). Cache the value if you need to call it very often.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Even without calling it often, this is still bad practice. Allocating an array just for the length property is silly, even if only done once.

Comment: @Hatefiend so what do you suggest?

Answer (score 13):

You can get the length by using `Myenum.values().length`

The `Enum.values()` returns an array of all the `enum` constants. You can use the `length` variable of this array to get the number of `enum` constants.

Assuming you have the following enum:

```
public enum Color
{
    BLACK,WHITE,BLUE,GREEN,RED
}
```

The following statement will assign 5 to `size`:

```
int size = Color.values().length;
```

Comment: `length` is not a method of an array, it is a property field, so you'd use it without parentheses.

Comment: @CyrilleKa: Thanks for notifying. Corrected it. :)

Answer (score 8):

To avoid calling **values()** method each time:

```
public class EnumTest {

    enum WORKDAYS {
       Monday,
       Tuesday,
       Wednesday,
       Thursday,
       Friday;

       public static final int size;
       static {
          size = values().length;
       }
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(WORKDAYS.size); // 5
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The enum.values() method is added by the Java complier and is not mentioned in the APIs.

[Where is the documentation for the values() method of Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659217/values-method-of-enum)

Answer (score 3):

`MyEnum.values()` returns the enum constants as an array.

So you can use:

```
int size = MyEnum.values().length
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a Kotlin answer and this question popped up. So, here is my answer.

```kotlin
enum class MyEnum { RED, GREEN, BLUE }
MyEnum.values().size // 3
```

This is another way to do it:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> sizeOf() = enumValues<T>().size
sizeOf<MyEnum>() // 3
```

Thanks to Miha_x64 for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626218/8583692).

Comment: See [this Kotlin issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48872) aiming to replace `Enum.values()` with a more modern and performant alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to the [answer of Yevhen Tkachenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66601869/4900653) it can be further optimized when using the enum values array, so the compiler calls `values()` only **once**:

```java
public class EnumTest {

    enum WORKDAYS {
       Monday,
       Tuesday,
       Wednesday,
       Thursday,
       Friday;

       public static final WORKDAYS[] values = WORKDAYS.values();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(WORKDAYS.values.length); // 5
      for (int i = 0; i < WORKDAYS.values.length; i++)
         System.out.println(WORKDAYS.values[i].name());
   }
}
```