# How can i use function reference inside enum?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, jvm

I have next enum declaration:

```
enum class Foo(val f: (String) -> String)
```

And next body:

```
BAR({obj -> obj.toString()}),
FOO({obj -> obj.toString()})
...
```

Can i somehow define function for reference? Something like this:

```
private val predicate: (String) -> String = {obj -> obj.toString()}
```

And next usage:

```
 FOO(::predicate)
```

This code don't compile at all (`Unresolved reference: predicate`).

**Update:**

I'am just created companion object:

```
 companion object Predicate {
    private fun predicate(): (String) -> String {
                return {obj -> obj.toString()}
            }
}
```

And then my IDE suggested me to use another type `KFunction0<(String) -> String>`. But i can i use function as param here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, it works fine for me. Do you have access to the private properties? Probably that is the issue!

Comment: @AnimeshSahu https://pl.kotl.in/16RBfHSJJ

Comment: https://pl.kotl.in/bN4W5xsyt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is a lambda (just like reference of function) by default you don't need to pass its reference.

```kotlin
private val predicate: (String) -> String = {obj -> obj.toString()}

enum class Foo(val f: (String) -> String) {
    FOO(predicate),
    BAR(predicate)
}
```

Works just fine. While if you have function defined in class/objects them you have to pass their respective reference.

**PS: Reference of a function generates lambda signature, while lambda has already a lambda signature**

Comment: But what if i need this function inside enum? Is it possible?

Comment: @SlandShow companion object is set up after the enum has been initialized for the purpose that you can use the enum inside it. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53524017/11377112

Comment: If i will use companion object with function, then i need to change type of lambda to `KFunction0<(String) -> String>`.

Comment: @SlandShow why that wouldn't even register. A KFunction0 is a lambda that takes no argument and returns a value in your case it is like: `() -> (String) -> String`