# Kotlin: convert from int to Enum

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to convert from int to my Enum in Kotlin?
I have the Enum:

```
enum class Rank(val value: Int) { UNITY(1), TEN(2), HUNDRED(3), THOUSAND(4) }
```

And I want to call something like:

```
val results = ints.mapIndexed { index, element -> getRomanDigit(element, Rank(ints.size - index)) }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an enum from a Int in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523948/how-do-i-create-an-enum-from-a-int-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be using [`first`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first.html) (it also has a [`firstOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html) alternative) like so:

```kotlin
val results = ints.mapIndexed { idx, e -> getRomanDigit(e, Rank.values().first { it.value == ints.size - idx }) }
// Or using a map for caching:
val ranks = Rank.values().map { it.value to it }.toMap()
val results = ints.mapIndexed { idx, e -> getRomanDigit(e, ranks[ints.size - idx]!!) }
```

This however seems like a case where you'd rather want a `data class` for the rank, as you cannot possibly map all possible values of `ints.size - idx` in enumerations:

```kotlin
data class Rank(val value: Int)
val results = ints.mapIndexed { idx, e -> getRomanDigit(e, Rank(ints.size - idx) }
```