# Appending a number to enum to get other enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, enumeration

I want to get the enum value in a for loop, by appending a number, like

```
enum example
{
Example_1,
Example_2,
Example_3,
.
.
.
Example_n
};
example x;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++
{x = Example_ + i; // if i = 5, I need Example_5
}
```

I want this implementation in C++11

Comment: Don't use an enum, use an array.

Comment: Are you asking in C or C++?

Comment: I already have enums in place which are widely used across my codebase. So can't change to array.

Comment: I am asking for c++ implemenation

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57346836/2466431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `Example_0` in the enum, then `Example_0 + 5` will give you an integer value equivalent to `Example_5`. Enums are just integers.

All this assuming that you don't explicitly assign a value to a certain enumeration constant - that's another story.

Comment: There are other enumrations in between, so I can use as you suggested. There is no proper offset between these specified enums

Comment: @Naren Then kindly _post the actual enum_ so that your question can be answered.

Comment: The enumeration definition looks like:
enum example
{
Example_1,
Temp_0,
Example_2,
Temp_1,
Temp_2,
Apple_1,
Example_3
}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate name with number to retrieve enum name and use enum value.

- With contiguous enum, you can use simple arithmetic.
- you can create `operator++` for your enum, resolve by switch:

  ```
  example operator++(example e)
  {
      switch (e) {
      case Example_1: return Example_2;
      case Example_2: return Example_3;
      case Example_3: return Example_4;
      // ...
      case Example_n: return Last;
      };
      throw std::runtime("value out of range");
  }
  ```

  and so, possibly

  `for (example e = Example_1: e != Last; ++e) {/*..*/}`
- using array to provide enum list:

  ```
  constexpr auto AllExamples() {
      constexpr std::array res{{Example_1,
                                Example_2,
                                /*..*/,
                                Example_n}};
      return res;
  }
  ```

  which allows:

  ```
  for (auto ex : AllExamples()) {/*..*/}
  f(AllExamples()[5]);
  ```
- or use map if you really have to play with names:

  ```
  std::map<std::string, example> ExamplesAsMap() {
      return {
          {"Example_1", Example_1},
          {"Example_2", Example_2},
          /*..*/
          {"Example_n", Example_n},
          {"Value_1", Value_1},
          {"Value_2", Value_2},
          /*..*/
          {"Value_n", Value_n}
          /**/
      };
  }
  ```

  And then

  ```
  const auto m = ExamplesAsMap();
  example x;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      x = m.at("Example_" + std::to_string(i));
      // ...
  }
  ```