# Retrive Values From Enum

Tags: c++, enums

How can i recieve a specific value from an enum from a given index.

```
enum genre { Pop, Jazz, Classic}; //enum
struct album
{

    string album_name;
    genre kind;
    int track_number;
    string tracks[5];
    string tracklocation;
};

void main()
{
    album x1;
    cout<<"Enter genre 0->pop, 1->Jazz, 2->Classic\n";
    cin>>temp;
    x1.kind=(genre)temp;   // typecasting for int to enum
    cout<<x1.kind<<endl;
}
```

When i run this code i just get the integer value i input , instead of the converted enum value

what i need is when user input 0,1 or 2 it needs to be converted using the enum to the relevant genre and saved in the stucture variable.

Comment: You might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57346836/2466431

Comment: You cannot.  Not like that anyway.  Enum's are converted to integers at compile time.  Look up the std::pair class.  Pairs allow you to link two types together and access the second through a pointer from the first.  A common approach is linking an enum to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put the identifiers (names) of an `enum` to `cout`. For example, the value of the name `Pi` in `enum`, suppose it's set to `3.14`. You directly wants the user would type that value, it'll show the string `Pi` in output stream, but no, it's only within supposed within the code. Enumeration just holds the constants.

By default, your declaration `enum {Pop, Jazz, Classic}` holds the constant values 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

Rather, you could use arrayed string to get a value. Consider the following example:

```
struct album {
    string album_name;
    string genre[3] = {"Pop", "Jazz", "Classic"}; // this one holds 0 = "Pop" ...
    int track_number;
    string tracks[5];
    string tracklocation;
};
```

And the driver code:

```
int main(void) {
    album x1;
    int temp;

    std::cout << "Enter genre 0->pop, 1->Jazz, 2->Classic\n";
    std::cin >> temp;

    std::cout << x1.genre[temp] << endl;
    // will display 0 = "Pop", 1 = "Jazz", 2 = "Classic"

    return 0;
}
```